# Oracle Sys Refcurser in a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

I'm having some trouble returning a pointer to the query.

Here is my current code:

```
create or replace procedure getRoute(route IN varchar, routeday IN varchar)
  return sys_refcursor is
  v_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    select DISTINCT BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE "Service", BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE "StopNo", 
  STOP_NAME "Near", BBT_STOPS.ROAD_NAME "On", BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME "Duration"    
    from BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS
    inner join BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE
    on BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.SERVICE = BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE
    inner join BBT_STOPS
    on BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE = BBT_STOPS.STOPREF
    where  (UPPER(BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE) LIKE UPPER('%'|| :route || '%')) AND 
      (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.TIMEUNTIL, 1, 2)) > TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')))
    ORDER BY BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE, BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME;


  return timetable;
end;
/

DECLARE
 rc refcursor;
BEGIN
  exec :rc := getRoute(:route, :routeday);
END;
```

I get a Syntax error on the first line saying "Expected AUTHID, EXTERNAL"  However I'm also not sure if the code i've written will execute correctly either. Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error printing REFCURSOR variable as OUT parameter in procedure in Oracle 11g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810620/error-printing-refcursor-variable-as-out-parameter-in-procedure-in-oracle-11g)

Comment: You are mixing a **procedure** with a **function**. Either create a function to return the ref cursor, or create a procedure with ref cursor as OUT parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle Documentation for `CREATE PROCEDURE` syntax can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm).

`CREATE PROCEDURE` does not have a return clause (that is for `FUNCTION`s); you should use an `OUT` parameter instead and remove the return statement at the end.

You also need to use `OPEN cursor_name FOR` to execute the `SELECT` query and associate it with the cursor.

Also - you don't need `:` infront of variables declared in the procedure's header. The `:name` syntax is for bind variables in SQL - PL/SQL handles binding of variables automatically without that syntax.

(You don't seem to be using the `routeday` argument so you could remove it if you aren't going to use it in the future).

Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure getRoute(
  in_route      IN  varchar,
  in_routeday   IN  varchar,
  out_cursor    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
is
begin
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
    select DISTINCT BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE "Service",
                    BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE "StopNo",
                    STOP_NAME "Near",
                    BBT_STOPS.ROAD_NAME "On",
                    BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME "Duration"    
    from BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS
         inner join BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE
         on BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.SERVICE = BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE
         inner join BBT_STOPS
         on BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE = BBT_STOPS.STOPREF
    where  (UPPER(BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE) LIKE UPPER('%'|| in_route || '%'))
    AND    (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.TIMEUNTIL, 1, 2)) > TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')))
    ORDER BY BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE, BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME;
end;
/
```

You could also consider using a strongly typed cursor instead of a weak cursor.

You can call it like this:

```
DECLARE
  route VARCHAR2 := 'abc';
  routeday VARCHAR2 := 'Tuesday';
  rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  getRoute(
    in_route    => route,
    in_routeday => routeday,
    out_cursor  => rc
  );
END;
/
```

Or if you do want to use bind variables (outside the PL/SQL block):

```
VARIABLE route VARCHAR2;
VARIABLE routeday VARCHAR2;
VARIABLE rc REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  route := 'abc';
  routeday := 'Tuesday';
END;
/    

BEGIN
  getRoute(
    in_route    => :route,
    in_routeday => :routeday,
    out_cursor  => :rc
  );
END;
/

PRINT :rc;
```

Comment: When I try to call the procedure, I get an error message with this: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 9:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'GETROUTE' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: I use this code to call the procedure: DECLARE
 rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  rc := getRoute(:route, :routeday, rc);
END;

Comment: Any idea why it's saying that it can't find the procedure?

Comment: Did it compile without errors? (run `SHOW ERRORS` after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` to check). Otherwise, are you calling it from the same user?

Comment: Managed to fix the error - your code to print the result was very useful :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OPEN FOR` syntax and function instead procedure, also `:` not needed in body code for parameters

```
create or replace function getRoute(route IN varchar, routeday IN varchar)
  return sys_refcursor is
  v_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open v_rc  FOR
    select DISTINCT BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE "Service", BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE "StopNo", 
  STOP_NAME "Near", BBT_STOPS.ROAD_NAME "On", BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME "Duration"    
    from BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS
    inner join BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE
    on BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.SERVICE = BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE
    inner join BBT_STOPS
    on BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.STOP_REFERENCE = BBT_STOPS.STOPREF
    where  (UPPER(BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE) LIKE UPPER('%'|| route || '%')) AND 
      (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(BBT_WEEKLYSCHEDULE.TIMEUNTIL, 1, 2)) > TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')))
    ORDER BY BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.SERVICE, BBT_JOURNEYSTOPS.JOURNEYTIME;


  return v_rc ;
end;
```

/

Also you can't use `EXEC` in pl\sql code.

```
DECLARE
 rc refcursor;
BEGIN
  :rc := getRoute(:route, :routeday);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately I still get the syntax error as previously mentioned

Comment: It's in Oracle SQL Developer. I think the other person that answered this question sorted it - it's because I was using procedure but using a return line!

Comment: As i said in my answer, you should use `FUNCTION` with `RETURN`. And remove `exec` in your PLSQL code