# How to write a stored procedure which return a result set

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How to write a stored procedure which return a result set?
  I am not able to understand the meaning of question especially
and also i need an example to understand in a simple way.

Comment: You need to use `REF_CURSOR`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27812983/3989608

Comment: The linked question is about printing a cursor once it has been returned not about how to return a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_Cursor(
  o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor FOR
  SELECT 'X' AS VALUE FROM DUAL;
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

If you then want to call the `PROCEDURE` and get the results you can do:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  get_Cursor( :cur );
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

Which will output:

```
CUR
---
VALUE
-----
X
```

**Update**:

Beyond the scope of the OP, but to answer your question about how else to print it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE print_Cursor(
  i_cursor IN SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  p_value VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH i_cursor INTO p_value;
    EXIT WHEN i_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_value );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  p_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  get_Cursor( p_cursor );
  print_Cursor( p_cursor );
END;
/
```

Comment: Actually i saw that before only but i didn't the idea. so i posted the question.

Comment: actually my intimation is write a procedure x which return a result set and not to print but i call that stored procedure x in procedure y and to print in this procedure.is it possible please suggest me.

Comment: Yes for that you need to use collections

Comment: can you give me one example

Comment: You don't need to use collections, you can just iterate over the cursor - see my update.

Comment: create or replace
procedure ax is 
type t1 is ref cursor;
v1 t1;
i emp%rowtype;
begin
open v1 for select * from emp;
loop
fetch v1 into i;
exit when v1%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(i.empno||','||i.ename);
end loop;
close v1;
end; this is procedure x but i need to print the result  in another procedure.can you give me an example

Comment: I have done in my update - if you want further clarification then you probably need to ask another question as this is beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: create or replace
PROCEDURE aproc1(
    cv_results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN cv_results FOR SELECT empno,ename,deptno FROM emp ;
END;

Comment: it is first procedure.it was compiled

Comment: create or replace
procedure aproc2 is
     x sys_refcursor;
      l_empno emp.empno%type;
      l_ename  emp.ename%type;
      l_deptno    emp.deptno%type;
   begin
  aproc1(x);
     loop
         fetch x into l_empno, l_ename, l_deptno;
        exit when x%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_empno || ' ' || l_ename || ' ' || l_deptno);
     end loop;
     end;

Comment: it is second procedure. i got the output .

Comment: 55 jak 47
441 uday 20
200 SHALINI 50
442 Trinath 20
104 KUMAR 20
22 ASD 1
45 SAIKIRAN 8
45 SAIIRAN 8
101 RAVI 50
45 prabha 8
110 NARAN 60
123 sachin 20
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database Nor.

Comment: but how it was executed  and what is the logic behind i am not able to understand. can you explain me.